# Rails css isn't pre-compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the gem 'gem 'rails_admin_nestable' to sort an ancestry enabled table.  It works fine in development, but I get the following error in production:

ActionView::Template::Error (rails_admin/rails_admin_nestable.css isn't precompiled):
    5:         = nested_tree_nodes @tree_nodes
    6: 
    7: 
    8: = stylesheet_link_tag 'rails_admin/rails_admin_nestable'
    9: = javascript_include_tag 'rails_admin/jquery.nestable'
    10: = javascript_include_tag 'rails_admin/rails_admin_nestable'

I have this line in my application.css

```
 *= require rails_admin/rails_admin_nestable
```

Here is a pic:

[image]

I didn't think that I needed to copy the stylesheet into app/assets/stylesheets because I assumed the gem would load it.

But, I went ahead and put it there and I still get the same error.

Thanks !!

PS - I'm using RubyMine to edit my app.  At the bottom of the directory list, it has "External Libraries".  I thought I'd see the above stylesheet somewhere in this list - but, I don't see it.

Comment: Have you run `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: Would I do it this way?  rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: Should this be true?    # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

Comment: You probably need to schedule those files for precompilation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042114/rails-assets-pipeline-with-yielded-javascript/15042331#15042331

Comment: `rake assets:precompile` creates files used in production. You don't need to pass through the environment variable.

Comment: I'm deploying my app using Capistrano.  Should I have a command in the deploy.rb to 'rake assets:precompile' ?

Comment: I have this in my Capfile  load 'deploy/assets' - Doesn't that do the rake assets:precompile?

Comment: My Capfile has this:      load 'deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy'